# How to store link in java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a csv file. In this when I add the image then it'll store on server and then that image's path/link. I am trying to parse it and write into csv file. This links length is very big. So in csv its put that path on line and again put new. How to solve this?

Java Code:

```
        File fXmlFile = new File("d:/Eff_SOR/formdata.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        List< Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
             Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
             if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
             map.put("Original_Price_signature", eElement.getElementsByTagName("original_price_signature").item(0).getTextContent());
             list.add(map);               
              }
        }       
        generateCsvFile("d:\\SOR\\SOR.csv", list );


 .......................
 ............................
 private static void generateCsvFile(String sFilename, List< Map<String, String>>  test) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFilename);         
               for (Map<String, String> map : test) {          


        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,String> mapEntry = (Map.Entry<String,String>) iterator.next();
           //ystem.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + ", value:" + mapEntry.getValue());

            writer.append(mapEntry.getValue());
            writer.append(",");
            iterator.remove();
        }
        writer.append(LINE_BREAK);
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not short link to affrodable size? You can delete some levels of folder on server, if it doesn`t help. May be use link cutter like http://goo.gl/, that convert you link to short variant pseudolink.

Comment: “So in csv its put that path on line and again put new.”— I read it several times and still don’t get what the problem is.

Comment: @Holger :Expected o/p :In csv -one record will show one line and next record on new line .Right now whats happens.one records show in two line because of that image link which is very ling so it write/put this value one new line not same line

Comment: As far as I can see your maps will always contain exactly one entry. So if you ever encounter commas or unintended line breaks in your CSV file they have nothing to do with your export method but come from the `getTextContent()` invocation on the DOM node, in other words, the text appears as stored in the XML file. It is not really *converted*.